# Download Project using Linux mint

Tags: openssh, linux-terminal

I am trying to download a project using Terminal of Linux Mint. I am using below command.
`scp -r UserName@ServerIPaddress:/home/username/public_html /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project`. But I am getting error `/opt/lampp/htdocs/public_html: Permission denied`.

I can login to server using `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write access to the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/public_html` on your local computer (which makes sense unless you run as a `root`).

You should clone to some other directory (`~`, `/tmp` or so) and then copy it to `/opt` with `sudo` or similar.